# Pulling MAX date from a separate access database

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to get the **MAX** date from a separate access database.

**Variables:**

```
dbpath = "C:\Portal\_Dev"
dbname = "Portal.accdb"
strpassword = "OpenSesame"
tblEngage = "tbl_engagement"
```

**Code that I have tried:**

```
CurrentDb.Execute "SELECT [MS Access;pwd=" & strpassword & ";database=" & dbpath & "\" & dbname & "].[" & tblEngage & "].CDP, Max([MS Access;pwd=" & strpassword & ";database=" & dbpath & "\" & dbname & "].[" & tblEngage & "].Open_Date) AS MaxOfOpen_Date" & _
         "FROM [MS Access;pwd=" & strpassword & ";database=" & dbpath & "\" & dbname & "].[" & tblEngage & "] " & _
         "WHERE [CDP] = '" & Text285 & "'"
```

This method I understand won't work due to the SELECT not being told to look in an external table:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "SELECT tbl_Engagement.CDP, Max(tbl_Engagement.Open_Date) AS MaxOfOpen_Date" & _
         "FROM [MS Access;pwd=" & strpassword & ";database=" & dbpath & "\" & dbname & "].[" & tblEngage & "] " & _
         "WHERE [CDP] = '" & Text285 & "'"
```

**Error Received:**

> The Select statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that
>   is misspelled or missing

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are these databases both located on the same machine?

Comment: Yeah, all on the same machines

Comment: Why not do it the easy way: link a table, and then use the `DMax` fucntion (anywhere, not just in VBA).  Do you know how to add a linked table?

Comment: I did consider this, but I thought having a linked table would make it more vulnerable to accessing the data by any unauthorised individuals? so felt best to use VBA to grab the data

Comment: uhh, depends what you mean by vulnerable, but no.  I suppose (without protecting the database when finished development), both the linked table or the VBA with the instructions to link the table, or both equally accessible.  *(Also just so you're aware, there's no such thing as "100% secure" with any shared MS Office document... but that's for a different question.)*

Comment: In fact, linking the table is a handy way to get the correct connection string you're trying to figure out.

Comment: Can't Execute a SELECT statement. Execute is for action statements (DELETE, UPDATE, INSERT). Use SELECT statement to set a recordset object. Also, need a space after MaxOfOpen_Date so the constructed SQL doesn't run together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open and set a recordset object with SELECT sql statement.

A simple example without password encryption:

```
Dim rs AS DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Max(Open_Date) AS MaxOfOpen_Date FROM tbl_Engagement IN '" & dbPath & "\" & dbname & "' WHERE CDP='" & Me.Text85 & "'")
Debug.Print rs!MaxOfOpen_Date
```

For a db with password, set and open ADODB connection object. This example uses early binding so need the MS ActiveX Data Objects library active.

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbpath & "\" & dbname & ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=OpenSesame"
rs.Open "SELECT Max(Open_Date) AS MaxOfOpen_Date FROM tbl_Engagement WHERE CDP='" & Me.Text85 & "';", cn
Debug.Print rs!MaxOfOpen_Date
```